# How to override lodash startcase functionality?

Tags: javascript, string, overriding, lodash

I have an array of strings with a large number of items(a sample size array with 3 elements is shown here):

```
['helloWorld', 'helloEarth', '28rounds']
```

I am using Lodash's StartCase to convert them into StartCase strings.

So, the output array would be: `['Hello World', 'Hello Earth', '28 Rounds']`

But I want a few items not to be altered even if we pass into lodash StartCase function. Is there an override operator which I can wrap the string in to so that lodash won't convert it.

I want `28rounds` to be printed as it is but others to be converted to StartCase

I don't want to do an equality check, that would be tightly coupled solution.

Comment: can't you separate the arrays into two, process them, then merge them again? I understand if the order of items is a concern that this might not be a great approach.

Comment: The order is important and also this array is simple, in my use case I could have a deeply nested object on which I want to apply the same logic without making it tightly coupled

Comment: I suggest looking into `https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#template`

Comment: Why not just map through and add some filter? 
`_.map(arr, a => {
  if (condition) { return _.startCase(a) } else {return a}
})`

Comment: @TalgatSaribayev what do you mean ?

Comment: Just edited my comment

Comment: I don't want to do tight coupling with if conditions, that is not scalable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String.replace()` (or lodash's replace) with a RegExp to catch sequences of letters, and replace them with a new string using `_.startCase()`:

```js
const arr = ['helloWorld', 'helloEarth', '28rounds']

const startCaseNoNumbers = str => str.replace(/^([A-Z]?[a-z]+)+/, _.startCase)

const result = arr.map(startCaseNoNumbers)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
```